# Can a parent unenroll a minor college student after giving permission and classes have begun?

Tags: minor, parental-rights, students

BOTH my mother and father signed an agreement with my principal and counselor to permit me to complete my high school graduation requirements in college. They BOTH also signed a separate college enrollment form where the specifically had to state they were giving me permission as a minor to attend the college. The (high) school district is paying for these classes as well as a bus pass for transportation.

I completed two summer classes with "A" grades in each. But my father now says that (in spite of the fact that this was discussed ad nauseam in SIX meetings and the fact that he signed multiple documents none of which say it was a "trial" and I'm not sure how much better than an "A" I could have scored) that his approval was conditional and he can withdraw it and "unenroll" me at any time.

Comment: I assume you are still a minor? In your state (assuming US?) are you still in compulsory education?