# If a parent withdraws a minor student from school, or prevents them from attending, is that a criminal violation of a mandatory attendance law?

Tags: parental-rights, students

Both of my parents signed an agreement with my high school to permit me to complete my high school graduation requirements in college. They both also signed a college enrollment form that specifically gave me permission as a minor and their dependent child to attend the college. My (high) school district is paying for the classes and a bus pass.

My father has stated his intent to renege on the agreement.

Since I am a minor, have not graduated from high school, and the grades from those 16 college classes and 2 labs were agreed to be accepted by the district as the graduation requirements for high school, isn't either withdrawing me from class, or preventing me from attending so that I fail, without enrolling me at another high school, or submitting a state mandated "intent to homeschool form" a violation of my state's compulsory attendance law that requires that all minors who have not yet graduated from high school attend school or show proof they are being homeschooled?

Comment: We can't describe the effects of your state's compulsory attendance law because you haven't told us what state it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a parent unenroll a minor college student after giving permission and classes have begun?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/94608/can-a-parent-unenroll-a-minor-college-student-after-giving-permission-and-classe)

Comment: @LaurensSwart OP posted two very similar questions that probably should be merged into one but so far neither of them has a good answer. So no, OPs other question doesn't answer this one.

Comment: @quarague, that is the default language that comes up when a question is marked as a duplicate.  Surprised it didn’t come with a close vote.  Good questions, but one should be closed.

Comment: These were my first two posts. I see them as two separate but interrelated questions. And not being able to sleep I spent the wee-hours rereading every document my parents signed. A better way to ask my original questions: (1) Where both of my parents signed consent forms for me to attend college classes in order to complete my high school graduation requirements as a "dual-enrollment" student can ONE parent unilaterally unenroll me, a minor they have custody of, from the program or unregister me from specific classes. (Both schools say no, but that is policy, not law.)

Comment: (2) Since the state has a compulsory attendance statute, and by my school district's policy I must complete the classes I am enrolled in or I will fail. Will my parents be held civilly and criminally responsible if I do not attend the classes they BOTH gave their permission for me to take. (The high school says that my guidance counselor and the principal must approve any requested change of classes, and it says that if I am withdrawn from enrollment I can only return in one of two ways (a) if less than a 10 day break with the same schedule, or (b) with approval of my counselor and principal.

Answer (score 3):

[Washington has such laws](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=28a.225&full=true). RCW 28A.225.010 states the exceptions to the compulsory attendance requirement, which includes: is attending private school or extension program, receiving home schooling, unable to attend including is in jail, religion, over 16 full-time employed and with parental consent. Also, also has GDE or has already satisfied graduation requirements. It isn't clear what graduation requirements have not been satisfied, I assume that you still must complete 1 credit of Calculus to satisfy the requirements. Therefore, you must take attend school, even if you don't take that class.

If you don't attend classes at the high school, the high school is required by RCW 28A.225.020 to provide written notice to the parents. Steps are taken to assure compliance with state law, i.e. phone calls and conferences with the parents, etc. It would be the responsibility of the school district to monitor the college's scheme that allows you to take high school classes at college.

The primary legal mandate is imposed on the parent:

> All parents in this state of any child eight years of age and under
> eighteen years of age shall cause such child to attend the public
> school of the district in which the child resides and such child shall
> have the responsibility to and therefore shall attend for the full
> time when such school may be in session

As described, the hypothetical child is not exempt, therefore the parents must compel the child to attend school, until the child becomes exempt. There is vast leeway in how that requirement can be satisfied, but it must be somehow satisfied.

Comment: I edited this from the state DoE website. I omitted specific legal references because I'm not really comfortable saying who I am or where I am located. "(I)f a student is 'absent without an acceptable excuse for part or all of 5 or more days on which school is held during a school semester,' he or she is considered a habitual truant... the court can levy fines of up to $500 and send the parents to jail for up to 30 days... for a first offense..." Having signed the agreement and enrollment form and then reneged probably negates any I had "a good reason" defense.

Answer (score -3):

### Not if you’re [old enough](https://www.findlaw.com/education/education-options/compulsory-education-laws-background.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20certain%20exceptions%2C%20most,they%20are%20at%20least%2016.)

Mandatory schooling is only required up to a certain age which varies by state - 16 is typical.

Comment: @Jen AFAIK, there is no such jurisdiction. You can lead a horse to water but you can’t make it graduate.

Comment: No, read it again, the law doesn't require graduation. It requires that all minors (persons under 18 in that jurisdiction) who haven't graduated from high school attend school or have an "intent to homeschool" form filed with the state DoE. One can quit school on one's 18th birthday without graduating.

Comment: FWIW, the public school has to accept all students who haven't graduated and haven't been expelled until they are 20.